# I want maximum keys count from json data in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this data:

```
 invid |            contents             
-------+---------------------------------
   109 | {"49": {"22000.00": "10.00"}}
   108 | {"49": {"22000.00": "312.00"}}
   106 | {"48": {"50000.00": "20.00"}}
   103 | {"50": {"1020000.00": "20.00"}}
   102 | {"48": {"50500.00": "20.00"}}
   101 | {"52": {"30060000.00": "0.00"}}
    89 | {"50": {"1020000.00": "2.00"}}
    88 | {"48": {"50000.00": "20.00"}}
    87 | {"50": {"1020000.00": "1.00"}}
    86 | {"50": {"10020000.00": "3.00"}}
    83 | {"48": {"50000.00": "30.00"}}
    82 | {"50": {"1020000.00": "4.00"}}
    81 | {"47": {"20000.00": "40.00"}}
    80 | {"48": {"50000.00": "200.00"}}
    79 | {"50": {"1020000.00": "20.00"}}
```

I want result:

```
[{50:5,48:4,49:3,52:1,47:1}]
```

or

```
[{'50':5,'48':4,'49':3,'52':1,'47':1}]
```

in descending order.

Comment: what you try so far?

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/

Comment: Shouldn't `50':5` be `50':6`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract all keys and the group the result:

```
select ky, count(*) as numkeys
from data
   cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(contents) as t(ky)
group by ky
order by ky;
```

If you want a single JSON array with the result you can use `jsonb_object_agg()`:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(ky, numkeys) 
from (
  select ky, count(*) as numkeys
  from data
    cross join lateral jsonb_object_keys(contents) as t(ky)
  group by ky
  order by ky
) t;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/HDB83302

Comment: both above ans are right just need to chage in order by numkeys

Comment: what changes i have to do if I want count of value of inner dict by outer dict key...   ans should be {49:322, 47:290 ,50:46,55:40,52:0}